# Realm object custom constructor

Tags: android, realm

I have a custom constructor for a class `ObjectA` that extends from RealmObject but for some reason my constructor is being called every time I query for an object of this class. Is this the expected behavior? What is the right way to create an instance of `ObjectA`? Right now I create an object the usual way `realm.createObject(ObjectA.class)`.

Comment: It sounds strange. Can you please share the code how did you do query? Maybe you can setup a breakpoint in the constructor and share the call stack as well? `realm.createObject(ObjectA.class)` is the right way to create Object, you can also do `MyObj obj = new MyObj(); obj = realm.copyToRealm(obj);1 .

Comment: Can you show us your ObjectA code? Are you setting a @PrimaryKey? Typically, you can just create a new object by using the new operator with the constructor of the object and then call `realm.copyToRealm()` or `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate()` on the object.